# Multiplication table in C#

Tags: c#, android-activity

I'm doing a simple exercises in C# and this is the problem: Write a program called TimeTable to produce the multiplication table of 1 to 9 as shown using two nested for-loops:

```
Sample output:
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Here's my code

```
int n = 9;

for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) 
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= n * n ;col++)
    {
        Console.Write(col);

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

My code is not working anyone can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
int n = 9;

for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) 
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(row * col);

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The problem was that for each `n` rows you were iterating through `n*n` columns and then each row had all of the numbers in the example table except in one line. Here, we iterate through each row, iterating through all the columns each time and printing the result of `row*col` which is the multiplication that's required.

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int n = 9;

Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList().ForEach(row => 
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList().ForEach(col => 
    { 
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0, 3}", row * col)); 
    });
    Console.WriteLine();
});
```

Comment: There is no benefit of this over the 2 nested loops method. Also you can use `Select` instead of `.ToList().ForEach()`.